# Requirejs with mocha

Tags: coffeescript, requirejs, mocha.js

RequireJS and mocha have some problem working together.
I figured this is because mocha does not wait for requireJS's asynchronous operations to finish and decides testing is done.

As a hot fix I wrapped requireJS 's loading calls in mocha's `it()` calls. 
Somehow mocha knows when I add a callback, that it should wait for the asynchronous methods to finish.

But I'd like to know whether there is no other, more convenient setup than the one I'm using now. The current setup isn't really nice nor flexible.

This is my test.coffee script:

```
describe 'Ink', ->
    describe '#constructor', ->
        it 'should return an Ink instance', ( done ) ->
            requirejs [ "build/ink/core/Ink" ], ->
                # commence testing
                a = new Ink( '<div></div>' )
                assert.equal( new Ink instanceof Ink, false )
                assert.equal( new Ink instanceof window.jQuery, true )

                done()

describe 'Mixin', ->

    f : ( Mixin ) ->
        # test mixin
        class A

            constructor : ( @a ) ->

        class m extends Mixin

            constructor : () -> @mixin_prop = 42
            increment : ( arg ) -> return arg + 1

        class B extends A
            Mixin.mixin( m, @ )

        b = new B()

        return b

    it 'should chain the constructor', ( done ) ->
        requirejs [ "build/ink/core/Mixin" ], ( Mixin ) ->
            b = f( Mixin )
            assert.equal( b.mixin_prop, 42 )
            done()

    it 'should add the methods from the mixin to the new class', ( done ) ->
        requirejs [ "build/ink/core/Mixin" ], ( Mixin ) ->
            b = f( Mixin )
            assert.equal( b.increment( 42 ), 42 )
            done()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I initialize my modules in beforeEach, and use a callback to trigger async:

```
describe...
    var Module
    beforeEach(function(callback){
        requirejs
            Module = loadedFile
            callback(); // suites will now run
    })
```

I have a bootstrap here: https://github.com/clubajax/mocha-bootstrap

Answer (score 1):

Mocha provides a `done` callback to the function you invoke with `it`, and it works nicely for this purpose. Here's an example of how I'm currently using it--note that I'm using require to load my test config as well, and obviously this is straight JS, not CoffeeScript, but it should obtain.

```
define([
  'chai',
  'SystemUnderTest'
], function(chai, SystemUnderTest) {

var expect = chai.expect;

describe('A functioning system', function() {

  it('knows when to foo', function(done) {
    sut = new SystemUnderTest();
    expect(sut.foo()).to.be.ok;
    done();
  });
});
```

So mocha's support for async testing, which you might 'normally' use to test async services, can also be used to support testing of asynchronously loaded modules.

[Mocha's async documentation](http://visionmedia.github.io/mocha/#asynchronous-code)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used requirejs in my tests, but I think the `before` function might help:

```
describe 'Mixin - ', ->
  before (done) ->
    console.log dateFormat(new Date(), "HH:MM:ss");
     requirejs [ "build/ink/core/Ink" ], ->
                # commence testing
                a = new Ink( '<div></div>' )
                assert.equal( new Ink instanceof Ink, false )
                assert.equal( new Ink instanceof window.jQuery, true )
    done()
  beforeEach ->
    ....
  describe ...
```